# SP fails but ExecuteReader is not throwing error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ado.net

I have a stored proc (having 1 select statement) written in sql which is generating an Devide by Zero error. 
But when I execute this SP from my C# code using ExecuteReader() I am unable to get error/exception. Does anyone know why?

Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UNABLE TO UNDERSTAND WHY but resolved my issue by using NextResult() method.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will get your exception when you start iterating over the reader results ...